# Hosting SVN Server on my PC to access remotely

Tags: svn, dns, dynamic-ip

I'm trying to connect to my SVN server (installed on my local PC) from a remote machine. After going through some SO questions and other guides, I have done the following steps:

1. SVN Server is installed on top of Apache server using HTTP protocol. I can access it by typing `http://localhost/svn` in my browser and in TortoiseSVN.
2. I have setup a DNS entry using free DNS service providers against my dynamic IP.
3. I can now type `http://MyFreeDNSName.FreeDNSServer.com` in a remote machine and that takes me to my machine.

The problem however is that this address opens the router's default page instead of the SVN page. This is the same page that I can access on the local machine by typing 192.168.1.1. So my question is, how can I configure my machine to pass the incoming request to SVN page instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to set up port forwarding on your router to point to your PC. Forward port 80 to the local IP address of your PC. Exactly how to do this will depend on your router model.
It might also help to give your PC a static IP address.

Comment: Precisely what I needed to do. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: **Never** port-forward port, on which router's web-server with admin pane function - **you'll lost admin access to router this way!!!**.

Answer (score 1):

You **must not** forward incoming request on port 80 from router to internal host's port 80.

You must select *any other* port, for which you'll add port-forward rules for forwarding from router:PORT to internal:80

Comment: Not sure if I understand you. Reading your comment above, it looks like you mean I'll not be able to open router's admin page after forwarding port 80. But that doesn't seem to be the case. I can still access both svn server and my router's admin page.

Comment: @dotNET - from LAN-side (AFAIR) you'll get router on 80 port. But not from WAN-side, where port-forward will play before router-server

Comment: @lazy in most cases you don't want the router admin page visible from the WAN anyway. I've never seen a case where forwarding port 80 blocks access from the LAN side.